# script error relating to naming convention

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have some data stored in a mat file spreadsheet when i try to run my kmeans.m script I get this error and I cant work out whats going on?

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT kmeans as a function    
Error in ==> kmeans at 10
    [clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data,
    K, 'options',opts, ...
```

Comment: Could you please list the full error?

Comment: that is the full error? ??? Attempt to execute SCRIPT kmeans as a function?

Comment: do you also have a script called `kmeans.m` in your MATLAB path?

Comment: hey yoda yes i do? (sorry for those that dont know ive been using matlab for about 4 days)

Comment: try renaming that script to something else. `kmeans` is a toolbox function that you're trying to use. If you also name your script as `kmeans.m`, then that has precedence in MATLAB's search and it calls it instead of the function you actually want, which causes the error you're seeing.

Comment: hey yoda thanks haha cant believe i didn't notice that but it worked!!! Woop. Can you post as a answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your script to something else. `kmeans` is a toolbox function that you're trying to use. If you also name your script as `kmeans.m`, then that has precedence in MATLAB's search and it calls it instead of the function that you actually want, which causes the error you're seeing.